# Can a UPC scanner talk to two POS systems at once?

Tags: usb, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to make a UPC (barcode) scanner talk to two POS systems independently and simultaneously, so when an item is scanned, the devise will send information to two different, non-integrated systems at (roughly) the same time?

I think this is probably a hardware question, because what I'm really wondering is if it's possible for two programs to talk to the same USB port at the same time.

Software insights are extremely welcome as well.

Thanks!

Leo

Comment: EE.SE deals with electronics design.  This question is about electronics usage.  It might work getter at SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if the barcode scanner is usb,  it can't be done. It should be done by the software controlling the scanner, then use some other port (serial, ethernet) to send the upc code to the other POS.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some luck using an Arduino as an intermediate proxy. Connect the UPC scanner to the Arduino and write software for it to emulate two seperate USB client devices. Then send the information on to two different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work with your existing scanner, but here's something you could do to accomplish this.

Replace your USB Scanner with a Serial/RS232 Scanner.  [Symbol Serial Scanner](https://posguys.com/barcode-reader-scanner_3/Symbol-LS2208_481/LS2208-7AZR0100DR_3048/) is one example.  Serial scanners aren't as common anymore, but depending on the model scanner you have, some just need a serial cable.  I'd talk to the manufacturer if it's possible to switch it to serial.

Make sure your POS will support a Serial Port scanner.  Not as common anymore, but most POS generally still support serial scanners.

Then purchase a [RS232 Splitter](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=4640&gclid=Cj0KEQjwy92wBRCl7trx4PaIo8EBEiQASPhtCyNSxFDQDlHlMm5pwLbe4EA_H2rgYRkyfQgBmDYcCPgaAo608P8HAQ&kpid=104640) to send the signal to both computers.

Now this is dependent on both computers having a serial port, or you can use a [USB to Serial adapter](http://www.icintracom.com/america/serial-converter-p-6657.html?osCsid=7170nkn4qsocgojfa2pl6pmqc3) if your computer doesn't have one.

Only caveat about the RS232 splitter is the range of the connection will be diminished as you are splitting that signal.

I'm curious as to what the end result you are trying to accomplish.  You have Two independent POS programs in your business.  Why are you wanting to scan the same item twice?  Is one POS for the warehouse to pick orders?

There seems to be no way currently to utilize one USB device on two computers at the same time.

If you had to use a USB scanner, the only idea I can come up with is using a [USB Switch Hub](https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/C2G-2-Port-USB-2.0-Manual-Switch-USB-peripheral-sharing-switch-2-ports/1628016.aspx?RecommendedForEDC=1691857&RecoType=RP&cm_sp=Product-_-Session&ProgramIdentifier=3).  You'd have to scan once for one POS, then press button on the usb-hub and scan again.

I Hope that helps.